# can't get media files in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, media

I deployed mu project in heroku successfully.

The only problem is that I can't find media files on heroku.

When I type `.../media/pic1.png` **locally** , I get the picture in the browser.

But, in **heroku,**, that gives

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:
>     ...../media/pic1.png
>   Raised by: django.views.static.serve
>
> Path ...../media/pic1.png doesn't exist

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^admin_platform/', include('admin_platform.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41648399/7976758 Do not store media files at Heroku.

Comment: ... and do not use `static.serve` in production. There's a big warning against doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting.py should look something like this:-

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')#by doing this there will be media folder in your main directory.
```

And in your url.py your code should be like this:-

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^admin_platform/', include('admin_platform.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)#this will help to access your media folder.
```

Hope this help in your project. :-)