# Change the template option based on the condition

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How to change the template tag based on another template tag.

task_count = {1 :3, 2: 0, 3: 1} --- i manually created

task_type = {1:rebuild,2:upgrade,3:provisioning} ---- this from table

I want to get the task count for ex: if the task id 1 then "Rebuild:3".

I tried the below code it's not working

```
{% for task in TaskTypeTag %}
{{task_count.{{task.id}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a custom filter.

```
@register.filter(name='cut')
def get_count(value, arg):
    task_count = {1 :3, 2: 0, 3: 1}
    return "{}:{}".format(value, task_count[arg])
```

Then you will be able to use it in your template.

```
{% for task in TaskTypeTag %}
    {{task.name|get_count:task.id}}
```

For more information, click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Thank you so much...and you have any idea y media directory is not working in Heroku

Comment: @MohamedNaveen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474150/using-heroku-for-django-media-files