# How can i get django to process media files on production?

Tags: django, django-media

How can i get django to process media files on production when DEBUG = False on heroku server?

I know that it’s better not to do this and that this will lead to a loss of performance, but my application is used only by me and my cat, so I don't think that this will be unjustified in my case.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474150/using-heroku-for-django-media-files

Comment: search here: https://elements.heroku.com/search/addons?q=media+files

Comment: Under that question suggest using AWS S3, - I want to handle the media through django. If this is not possible in principle, tell me.

Comment: you can refer the django docs for managing media files. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this won't work is because the Heroku file system is ephemeral, meaning any files uploaded after your app code is pushed will be overwritten anytime your app is restarted. This will leave your app with image links in the DB which lead to non-existent files.

You can read more about it here:

> https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Your best bet is using a bucket like Amazon S3 to upload your files to. It costs almost nothing for small use, and is very reliable.

> https://blog.theodo.com/2019/07/aws-s3-upload-django/