# Django project does not display images in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I upload the project to heroku, and change DEBUG=True to DEBUG=False, the images stop showing

That's my static and media root

```
STATIC_ROOT = Path(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = Path(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, by changing debug to false, you've put django into 'production' mode, which changes what is necessary for static files to be found. This is done because the 'dev' method is not proven secure.

For what to do in horoku, the [horoku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) has you covered:

For more information, the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) talk about the process as well

Comment: My static files are working fine, my problem is only with media files

Comment: Media files are a different kettle of fish.  Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474150/using-heroku-for-django-media-files